# System.MarshalByRefObject Visual Studio 2019 Load Test

Tags: performance-testing, visual-studio-2019, load-testing, visual-studio-loadtest

I am using VS 2019, I did setup for a load test. I am trying to run web performance test under remote server (controller/agents). I am seeing  an error 
"The Augument type 'System.MarshalbyRefObject' cannot be converted into parameter type 'Microsoft.vISUALStudio.TestTools.Common.FileCopyService.'

I have Visual Studio 2010 Enrerprise version 16.5.5

Any Idea about this issue ?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This is actually a bug found in the Visual Studio 2019 Enterprise.

If you try running a load test or web performance test using remote execution on a distributed test setting with VS 2019, it gives you the error but if you run the same with VS 2017, it will work.

I've already logged this issue and it's currently under investigation.
https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/1081628/issue-when-running-web-performance-and-load-test-u.html